# django-grappelli Autocomplete Lookups with multiple foreign key fields

Tags: django-grappelli

I have a model with two fields that are foreign keys to other models.

```
class Homepage(models.Model):
  featured_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.user')
  featured_story = models.ForeignKey('site_stories.story')

  @staticmethod
  def autocomplete_search_fields():
     return ("featured_user__icontains", "featured_story__icontains",) # Is this right?


class HomepageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  raw_id_fields = ('featured_user', 'featured_story',)
  autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
    'fk': ['featured_user'],
    'fk': ['featured_story']  # <====== What should this be???
  }
admin.site.register(Homepage, HomepageAdmin)
```

After [reading the admin docs](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#autocomplete-lookups) and trying a few things, it became clear that you *literally* need to use the label "fk" for grappelli to apply the autocomplete lookup formatting to a field.  So... how can I do this with this model, where there are multiple foreign key fields?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class HomepageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   raw_id_fields = ('featured_user', 'featured_story',)
   autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
   'fk': ['featured_user','featured_story'],
   }
```

Comment: Oh, duhhhhh.  -1 to me for being an IDIOT.